# Raspberry Pi suddenly filtering all ports

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a Pi that I'm using as a headless music server, running Raspbian, accessed using both MPD and Subsonic. It's been working perfectly for the last month, no issues, but as of this past week I've started being unable to connect. The Pi does not respond to pings, drops ssh requests, and nmap shows all 1000 ports as filtered. I have changed no settings, and have only used the Pi to listen to music, so I am very unsure as to what the issue could be all of the sudden.

I have a static IP assigned by the router, and always check to make sure I'm using the correct IP, so this is not the issue. At some point, rebooting the router allowed me to connect for about 10 minutes, but now even that doesn't work.

Rebooting the Raspberry Pi doesn't do anything to help.

Comment: What is if you reboot the RasPi?

Comment: Yeah, rebooting doesn't do anything to help.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Maybe the ethernet cable is broken. Have you checked it?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian (forgot to mention!), and I'm using the onboard wifi chip. I wonder if switching to ethernet would help?

Comment: If you can, using the wired connection is worth a try. Usually that works out of the box without any configuration. Maybe at least only to get a connection and look what's going wrong with WiFi. Is it Raspbian Buster?

Comment: as last resort: unplug power cord (not best practice) then remove SD card and mount it using another pc for further investigation (i.e. to read the logfiles)

Comment: Okay, I plugged into ethernet and things were going great for a few weeks. However yesterday, without changing anything, the same problem has reemerged. Maybe this is just a problem with my ISP?